# How to Split those regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

Here i have following strings ,

```
"#,##0.00"
"\"$\"#,##0.0000"
```

I need to split using regular expressions.

My Expected output is

```
"#,##0.00" => 2 (decimal)
"\"$\"#,##0.0000" => $4(4 decimal with $)
```

How to convert can u please suggest any way.

Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far? Try [`Regex.Matches("#.##0.00", @"^(?:""(\$)"")?.*?(0+)$")[0]`](http://ideone.com/RXYrLr) and use both groups.

Comment: Thanks it's working.. but for 2nd one not only for $ symbol it has may be another char in this case how to split?

Comment: @AkbarBasha: http://ideone.com/dlyPnA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^(?:"([^"]+)")?.*?(0+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:"([^"]+)")?` - 1 or 0 sequences of:

  - `"` - a double quote
  - `([^"]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more chars other than `"`
  - `"`
- `.*?` - any characters other than newline, 0 or more repetitions
- `(0+)` - Group 2 capturing 1 or more zeros
- `$` - end of string

And here is a C# demo:

```
var pat = @"^(?:""([^""]+)"")?.*?(0+)$";
var match = Regex.Match("#.##0.00", pat);
if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Length.ToString());
} // => 2
// With "\"$\"#,##0.0000" input: $4
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/dlyPnA)